# Django, filtering mysql database

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have `due_date` column in DB and trying to filter rows by the value of that column. So the values in the column looks like `"2020-01-20"` and I am trying to filter it till year and month. NOT till **Day**  In the function below:

```
def retrieve(request):

    date = "2020-01"       

    tasks = Task_Histories.objects.all().filter(due_date=date)
    serializer = InvocesSerializer(invoces, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I arrange DB column value before matching it in the `filter()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `startswith` so you can filter by month or by year, or millennium :)

```
Task_Histories.objects.filter(due_date__startswith=date)
```

Comment: this little touch saved me a lot. Thank you. will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Django [**`DateField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField) in your models. If so, use [**`__year`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year) and [**`__month`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month) filter

```
tasks = Task_Histories.objects.filter(due_date__year='2020',due_date__month='01')
```